# CPQ: Marking a quote as "Ordered" does not create all Order Products

Tags: cpq

I'm currently at a loss: We have several Subscription products.
I can configure them in the configurator just fine.

Now I create a new quote with 2 of those products (i.e. 2 quote lines with a different product each). Each has a Quantity > 0 (e.g. 25) and a properly calculated price based on the subscription period.
Afterwards I mark the quote as "Ordered".

Now CPQ only creates 1 Order Product for one of the Quote Lines but not the other.

Could anyone help me out here what potentially could prevent CPQ from creating an Order Product?

What I have checked so far:

1. Validation Rules: Apart from the 4 ones that come with the CPQ package, none exist, that might prevent an Order Product from being created.
2. I've also tried this by deactivating these 4 rules.
3. I ready that if Quantity is "0", no Order Product will be created. This is also not the case. Both quantities are > 0.
4. The error happens only for one particular product. It is not configured any different than the others, as far as I can tell. It is a Percent-of-Total (PoT) product.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.